# How do I adapt a pure virtual method from a template to the class that inherits from it?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typename

Let's say I have this example template:

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
virtual T* ReturnPtr() = 0;
};
```

And then I inherit from it:

```
class Buffer; //some class
class BufferWrapper : public Wrapper<Buffer>
{
virtual Buffer* ReturnPtr(); //<< (1.)
}
```

1. Is this the way to do it properly? When I write it like this it
   gives me no intellisense errors, but once I write ReturnPtr()
   somewhere,it tells me "the object has type qualifiers that are not
   compatible with the member function".
2. Does this mean it's impossible to use virtual methods like that?

Comment: Remove the `virtual` from the declaration in `BufferWrapper`.

Comment: that doesn't change it :( maybe it's just illegal to do it like that?

Comment: Can you show where you're calling `ReturnPtr`?

Comment: Your code is perfectly OK. If you have an actual compiler error and you don't know how to fix it, please show it. IntelliSense is not to be trusted blindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellisense shows that message when you are calling a non-`const` function on an object that is `const`. As we can see, `ReturnPtr` is non-const. There are generally two reasons you might see this message. The first is when you are trying to call `ReturnPtr` on a `const` object of type `BufferWrapper`:

```
const BufferWrapper bw;
bw.ReturnPtr(); // Can't call non-const member function on const object
```

The second is when your `BufferWrapper` object is a data member of a class and you are calling `ReturnPtr` on it from within a `const` member function of that class:

```
struct SomeClass
{
  BufferWrapper bw;

  void SomeClass::SomeFunc() const
  {
    bw.ReturnPtr(); // Cannot call non-const member function here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes,it turns out you are right - the problem was,that I was calling ReturnPtr inside another method that is const.When I removed the const from the other method,everything worked out fine.

Comment: @Bogomil you can add a `const` overload of `ReturnPtr` to your class that returns a `const Buffer*` so that you can have both `const`-correctness and compilable code.